# tikz set coordinate to another

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}    
\begin{document}    
\footnotesize

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, >=stealth]
\draw[->] (-1.5,0) --node[below right]{$0$} (1.5,0) coordinate[label=below:$x$](x);
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[left]{$y$};;
\draw (0,0)coordinate(o) circle [radius=1cm] (1, 0) node[below right] {$1$};
\coordinate [label={left:$(\cos (\alpha), \sin (\alpha))$}] (p) at (125:1);
\coordinate [label={below:$\cos (\alpha)$}] (q) at (p|-o);
\coordinate [label={right:$\sin (\alpha)$}] (v) at (-o|p);
\draw (o)--(p)--(q)--(o)--cycle;
\pic[draw,"$\alpha$",angle radius=15pt,angle eccentricity=1.3,->]{angle=x--o--p};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the line I am having trouble with is this:

```
\coordinate [label={right:$\sin (\alpha)$}] (v) at (-o|p);
```

because it gives me the error

> Runaway argument?
>   o|p); \draw (o)--(p)--(q)--(o)--cycle; \pic [draw,"$\alpha $",angle r\ETC.
>   ! Paragraph ended before \tikz@next was complete.
>    
>                      \par 
>   l.18

?

however, if I change the code to use sample numbers instead of coordinates, e.g.

```
    \coordinate [label={right:$\sin (\alpha)$}] (v) at (0, 0.75);
```

it does work.

What I am trying to achieve is this:
[image: what I want to achieve]
but currently, the `sin (α)` is not correctly positioned (as it is my sample using `0` and `0.75`).
Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be `(o|-p)`

Comment: Don't scale `\footnotesize` up by 1.5. Use the appropriate font size to start with. With optical sized fonts, such as the defaults, larger font sizes are not simply scaled versions of smaller ones. Rather the glyphs are adjusted depending on the font size.

Comment: Note, every label is itself a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would draw your images as show image below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
       > = stealth,
    font = \footnotesize
                    ]
% cordinates
\coordinate[label=below right:$0$] (o) at (0.0,0);
\coordinate[label=below left: $x$] (x) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate[label=below left: $y$] (y) at (0,1.5);
% axis
\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (x);
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (y);
% circle
\draw (o) circle (1cm)
      (1,0) node[below right] {$1$};
\draw[thick] (o) -- (125:1) coordinate[label=left:{$(\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$}] (p);
% labels
\path[draw=gray, densely dashed, very thin]
    (p) -- ([yshift=-1] p |- o) node[below] {$\cos\alpha$}
    (p) -- ([xshift= 1] p -| o) node[right]{$\sin\alpha$};
\pic[draw,"$\alpha$",angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.3,->]{angle=x--o--p};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```