# tikz and package german in one document are not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, german

I am using the following code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{german}
% ^^^^^^^^^^^^
% This is where the error comes from

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, angles, quotes}
\begin{document}    

Die Werte der \textbf{trigonometrischen Funktionen} für beliebige Winkel $\alpha \in R$ definiert man anhand des Einheitskreises mit Radius 1 und Mittelpunkt $(0, 0)$.
                                                  % ^^^
                                                  % Regardless of whether or not there is an 'ü' here, it does not work.
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, >=stealth]
% cordinates
\coordinate[label=below right:$0$] (o) at (0.0,0);
\coordinate[label=below left: $x$] (x) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate[label=below left: $y$] (y) at (0,1.5);
% axis
\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (x);
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (y);
% circle
\draw (o) circle (1cm)
      (1,0) node[below right] {$1$};
\draw[thick] (o) -- (125:1) coordinate[label=left:{$(\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$}] (p);
% labels
\path[draw=gray, densely dashed, very thin]
    (p) -- ([yshift=-1] p |- o) node[below] {$\cos\alpha$}
    (p) -- ([xshift= 1] p -| o) node[right]{$\sin\alpha$};
\pic[draw,"$\alpha$",angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.3,->]{angle=x--o--p};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

as recommended in [another question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393075/143732) and the code does work if I do not use `\usepackage{german}`, however, if I do, I get the error

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
>    
>                      \errhelp 
>   l.12 ...nate[label=below right:$0$] (o) at (0.0,0)
>                                                     ;
>   ?

Why is that and is there any way to fix this or are there any alternatives for the package `german`?

Comment: The `german` package is totally outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `german` package is outdated for a long time by now. Use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` **and** `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` instead in order to prevent errors by special shorthands and language-specific active characters in conjunction with `tikz`.

Also use `in \mathbb{R}` rather than `\in R`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% ^^^^^^^^^^^^
% This is where the error comes from

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, angles, quotes,babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}    

Die Werte der \textbf{trigonometrischen Funktionen} für beliebige Winkel $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ definiert man anhand des Einheitskreises mit Radius 1 und Mittelpunkt $(0, 0)$.
                                                  % ^^^
                                                  % Regardless of whether or not there is an 'ü' here, it does not work.
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, >=stealth]
% cordinates
\coordinate[label=below right:$0$] (o) at (0.0,0);
\coordinate[label=below left: $x$] (x) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate[label=below left: $y$] (y) at (0,1.5);
% axis
\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (x);
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (y);
% circle
\draw (o) circle (1cm)
      (1,0) node[below right] {$1$};
\draw[thick] (o) -- (125:1) coordinate[label=left:{$(\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$}] (p);
% labels
\path[draw=gray, densely dashed, very thin]
    (p) -- ([yshift=-1] p |- o) node[below] {$\cos\alpha$}
    (p) -- ([xshift= 1] p -| o) node[right]{$\sin\alpha$};
\pic[draw,"$\alpha$",angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.3,->]{angle=x--o--p};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't know it was outdated. Also I knew about `\mathbb{R}` and in my original code I used the `amssymb` package (along with multiple other packages) but I removed them to produce a minimal example.